# Connes' idea to use the hyperfinite $III_1$ factor for the archimedian place of Spec(Z)?

Tags: reference-request, von-neumann-algebras, field-with-one-element

I recently gave a talk, where I talked about the tensor category
of (all, not just finite index) bimodules over the hyperfinite $III_1$ factor.

Vaughan Jones, who was in the audience, later told me that he remembered that Alain Connes had suggested using that tensor category as version of the place $p=\infty$ of $Spec(\mathbb Z)$. I was unable to track down a reference, or to make any sense of that suggestion. Has someone else heard of that? Could someone explain the idea and/or name a reference?

Comment: You mean archimedean?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'll fix the title.

Comment: http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/coll-55.pdf p.626 e.g.

Comment: @user5831: That's certainly going in the right direction. I'm not sure what the right question to ask is... Maybe: what is the function field analog of the category of all bimodules over a $III_1$ factor?

Comment: ...or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bost%E2%80%93Connes_system)